# How can I align equations numbering vertically when using `\includegraphics` instead of typesetting the equation?

Tags: math-mode, graphics, equations, numbering, amsmath

Here is the output I get when I use `\includegraphics` to import a figure in an equation environment:

[image]

But I want the output to be like this (edited photo):

[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{IEEEtran}

    \usepackage{graphicx}   
    \usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{my_figure.png}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `graphicx` with its extension `adjustbox`, and use this code:

```
\adjincludegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth, valign = c]{my_figure.png}
```